# Exclude specific file from webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle

In my React app I'm using Webpack. Here is my webpack.config:

```
"use strict";

var path = require("path");
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require("webpack-notifier");
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./Scripts/reactApp/index.jsx",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./Scripts/reactApp/build"),
        filename: "react_bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, path.resolve(__dirname, "./Scripts/reactApp/translations/he.translations.json")],
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, path.resolve(__dirname, "./Scripts/reactApp/translations/he.translations.json")],
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    plugins: [new WebpackNotifierPlugin(), new BrowserSyncPlugin()]
};
```

I'm trying to exclude from bundle `he.translations.json` 
But webpack included it whatever.

[image]

Can you explain me what I do wrong? 
Sorry in advance, I'm new in webpack.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do (from [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition))

```
...
exclude: [/node_modules/, path.resolve(__dirname, 'Scripts/reactApp/translations/he.translations.json')],
...
```

There's no dot in the path and, of course, assuming you have the wepback config file in the proper place.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Works with WebPack 5.


```
 {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
```